# Locust-looking bugs eating my tree leaves. How do I make them stop?

Tags: trees, pest-control, tree-care

I put some trees in behind my house in Israel. These locust looking things showed up and started eating the leaves. How can I get rid of them? I prefer organic solutions, but am not too worried about it.[image]

[image]

Comment: They look soft bodied, the standard 5 ml of dish soap to 1 liter of water in a pressure sprayer so you can get coverage should do the job. Repeat as necessary.

Comment: Took me a minute to find the bug in the first picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks more like a [bush-cricket](http://www.greatfen.org.uk/wildlife/inverts/bushcrickets) to me, still without wings (so nymph), I don't know which species.

To get rid of them is difficult, you can try glue traps (but don't know how long they hold after rain). There are more ways to get rid of them described [here](https://www.getridofthings.com/get-rid-of-crickets/), so choose what is best for your situation.

Comment: Would diatomaceous earth work?

Comment: @BorisK, interesting idea. I have no experience with it, but when I read about it it sounds like a not so harmful method for humans. How do you want to apply this?

Comment: Like this: https://www.maximumyield.com/organic-pest-control-diatomaceous-earth-how-to-apply-it/2/2886